# midori allow scripts to open popups

Tags: raspberry-pi, autostart, midori

I'm trying to autorun [midori browser](http://midori-browser.org/) on my raspberry pi zero.

I'm running the following command in /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart: `@midori -e Fullscreen -a [WEBSITE_URL]`

The midori browser is starting up automatically and going to the website I want it to go, but it won't show any popups.

In the midori browser itself (not the one that started up automatically) I've enabled 'Allow scripts to open popups'.

Is it possible to set this setting inside the autostart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer over here: https://github.com/elalemanyo/raspberry-pi-kiosk-screen using epiphany-browser instead of midori.